# Typeahead in JSP

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3

When using typeahead in my JSP, it is not recognized. I've tried different ways to import files, both offline and online.

```
<script src=js/typeahead.jquery.js></script>

           or 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.js">
```

My code @Html

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input class="typeahead" id="input-address" type="text" placeholder="Your Address">
</div>
```

My code @JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input-address").typeahead({
        source: ['Washington', 'Sydney', 'Amsterdam', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
        , minLength: 
    });
});
```

Even though it is done as recommended, I did not get the result of typeahead.

I wait, thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the console?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes, I have already seen the Console. I am not receiving any errors.

Comment: Smells like you haven't included the necessary JS libraries (jQuery and Typeahead).

Comment: Exactly chrylis!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a minimal working example.  You need to load Boostrap and jQuery.  You can select the input element by class or ID.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<input id="input-address" type="text" placeholder="Your Address">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"/></script>
<script>
var $input = $("#input-address");
$input.typeahead({source: ['Washington', 'Sydney', 'Amsterdam', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typeahead mentions it has a dependency on jQuery [on github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#user-content-getting-started) but doesn't mention bootstrap — are you sure you _need_ bootstrap?

Comment: @David,

The typeahead worked after writing the line of your code. I believe it is the versioning of the import I had made of cdnjs version 4.0.2, bootstrap-3-typeahead.

`<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "// cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"`, thank you!

Comment: @Stephen P - yes I tried it without Bootstrap, it relies on a Bootstrap drop-down list/menu.

Comment: @ Stephen P,
Yes, I relied on a Bootstrap drop-down list / menu. Thanks!